# Using Chai to test if POST /users password was encrypted

Tags: node.js, express, mocha.js, chai, bookshelf.js

I am having a difficult time understanding how this works. I understand how to check and match a users plain text password. However, with bcrypt encryption, I would need to make a database call to check that the password was in fact encrypted? 
Here's the code I'm working with:

```
describe('create (POST /users)', function () { 
   it('succeeds, with encrypted password', function (done) {
      chai.request(expressApp)
        .post('/users/')
        .send({
          email: 'johndoe@gmail.com',
          username: 'johndoe',
          first_name: 'John',
          last_name: 'Doe',
          password: '123456789',
          phone_number: '+1.888.12456'
        })
        .end((err, res) => {
          res.should.have.status(201)
          res.should.be.json
          res.body.should.have.property('id', 2)
          res.body.should.not.have.property('password')
          User.forge({ id: res.body.id })
             .fetch()
             .then((user) => {
               console.log(user.attributes.password) // prints 123456789     
               return bcrypt.compare(user.attributes.password, res.body.password).then (function (res) { 
               res.should.equal(true)
             })
           .fetch()
           .catch(err)
         done(err)
        })
    })
```

Here is the code for the user model using Bookshelf.js

```
  initialize () {
    this.on('saving', this.encryptPassword)
  },

  encryptPassword (model, attrs, options) {
    if (attrs.password) {
      return bcrypt.hash(model.attributes.password, 10).then((hash) => {
        model.set('password', hash)
      })
    }
  },
```

The test is currently passing but I know it is not correct, can someone help please me understand this?

Answer (score 0):

bcrypt has a [`compare`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt#to-check-a-password) function which tests a plaintext password against a hash to see if it matches, and calls back with any error and a boolean true/false. You'll need to use that with the User object you're pulling out of the db and test the result.

Comment: thanks! definitely need to check the docs first. However, I'm still struggling with what needs to be done still. I updated the code but I am still not sure where to go from there

Comment: That's all you need -- if the result from bcrypt.compare is true then the encrypted password in the User matches the plaintext password you're testing against it.